# Creating a Crystal Report with dataset populated by list

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, dataset

I have created a crystal report in VS 2012 named ItemSalesReport. I have created a dataset and in designview added a datatable named ItemSalesTable with 4 columns: `ItemName, Quantity, UnitPrice and Total.`

When adding my report, I selected all 4 columns under ProjectData -> ADO.NET Datasets. I was following this guide http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12694/Creating-Crystal-Reports-using-C-with-Datasets

I now want to run the report with data not from a database but from a list - `ItemSalesList` . Do I still need the use of a DataAdapter?

I have this list

```
List<ItemSales> ItemSalesList = new List<ItemSales>();

public class ItemSales
{
      public string ItemName { get; set; }
      public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
      public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
      public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

How do I populate the datatable in the dataset in order to view the values on the report?

Also, my CrystalReportViewer does not seem to have a ReportSource property.

Comment: I found an answer for my question above here. Really good read. http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84408/datasets-and-tables-without-a-database/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to make properties manually.
Just go through the wizard for making a crystal report. It will manage all thing all that need is proper connection with DB and selection of tables.

[I think video will help full](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5C9fwFyJQxQ)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am not getting ot posting anything to a DB, I send data to another app that handles the DB posting.